# Visual Studio 2017 constantly requesting jsconfig / tsconfig / node_modules

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After a recent reinstall I have found that I am having performance issues with VS 2017. I spotted today that it is constantly requesting files from the server on which the code I am hosting is located. See fiddler output. It is trying to load `"/node_module/%40types"`, `"/node_modules"`, `"jsconfig.json"`, and `"tsconfig.json"`, none of which exist. They are being called by svchost over and over and over. I am not sure what has changed, or how to overcome it, does anyone have any idea's? Thanks in advance.

[fiddler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHZQi.jpg)